# I want to customize the android youtube player api's layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-youtube-api

I want to customize the YouTube player API for Android like below player.
Player in the image is actually used in an app on play store and I want to customize my youtube player like this:

[image]

Comment: I would love to help you but I need to know first what research you have done. For example, have you used Google already to search what others have tried? I found this https://medium.com/@soffritti.pierfrancesco/customize-android-youtube-players-ui-9f32da9e8505

Answer (score 0):

Use YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS style in YouTube player api.

```
player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS)
```

And use -

`YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener` and `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener`

to update your custom controls UI.